# compareing and merging two TreeMaps

Tags: java, iterator, key-value, treemap

I have produced two multimaps in Java like this:

```
TreeMap1 = {key1=[a,b,c], key2=[d,e,f]}
TreeMap2 = {key1=[j,k], key2=[z,p]}
```

How can I add the values of TreeMap2, with similar key as in TreeMap1, to the values of TreeMap1, and produce a third TreeMap Like:

```
TreeMap3 =  {key1=[a,b,c,j,k], key2=[d,e,f,z,p]}
```

This Method gives me nothing.

```
public TreeMap<String, List<String>> make_TreeMap3(){
    for(Entry<String,List<String>> entry_t1 :this.map_FuncType.entrySet()){ 
        for(Entry<String,List<String>> entry_t2 : this.map_AufOrgUserField.entrySet()){
            if(entry_t2.getKey().contains(entry_t1.getKey())){              
                entry_t2.getValue().addAll(entry_t1.getValue());
            }   
        }
    }
    return map_mergOrgandType;  
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should return `entry_t2` and not `map_mergOrgandType` ?

Comment: Where did `map_mergOrgandType` even come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
TreeMap<String, List<String>> treeMap3 = new TreeMap<>(treeMap1);
for (String k : treeMap3.keySet()) {
    if (treeMap2.containsKey(k)) {
        treeMap3.get(k).addAll(treeMap2.get(k));
    }
} 
return treeMap3;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to do in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) if you're open to using a 3rd party library.

```
public class MultimapMerge {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Multimap<String, String> map1 = TreeMultimap.create();
    map1.put("key1", "a");
    map1.put("key1", "b");
    map1.put("key1", "c");
    map1.put("key2", "d");
    map1.put("key2", "e");
    map1.put("key2", "f");

    Multimap<String, String> map2 = TreeMultimap.create();
    map2.put("key1", "j");
    map2.put("key1", "k");
    map2.put("key2", "z");
    map2.put("key2", "p");

    Multimap<String, String> map3 = TreeMultimap.create();
    map3.putAll(map1);
    map3.putAll(map2);
    System.out.println(map3);
  }
}
```

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: thanks for your help, but i prefer not to use third party lib in this case.